# Python: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_username'

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, attributeerror, nonetype

I'm working on a hangman program that also has user accounts objects. The player can log in, create a new account, or view account details, all of which work fine before playing the game. After the game has completed, the user's wins and losses are updated. Before exiting the program, if I try to view the account (the viewAcc function) I get the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_username'.
```

When I run the the program again, I can log in to the account, but when I view the account info the wins and losses haven't been updated. Any help would be appreciated, I have to turn this in for class in about 8 hours.

Heres the class code:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, username, password, name, email, win, loss):
        self.__username = username
        self.__password = password
        self.__name = name
        self.__email = email
        self.__win = int(win)
        self.__loss = int(loss)

    def set_username (self, username):
        self.__username = username

    def set_password (self, password):
        self.__password = password

    def set_name (self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_email (self, email):
        self.__email = email

    def set_win (self, win):
        self.__win = win

    def set_loss (self, loss):
        self.__loss = loss

    def get_username (self):
        return self.__username

    def get_password (self):
        return self.__password

    def get_name (self):
        return self.__name

    def get_email (self):
        return self.__email

    def get_win (self):
        return self.__win

    def get_loss (self):
        return self.__loss
```

And here's my program's code:

```
import random
import os
import Account
import pickle
import sys
#List of images for different for different stages of being hanged
STAGES = [
'''
      ___________
     |/         |
     |          |
     |         
     |         
     |          
     |         
     |
     |
     |
_____|______
'''
,
'''
      ___________
     |/         |
     |          |
     |        (o_o)
     |         
     |          
     |         
     |
     |
     |
_____|______
'''
,
'''
      ___________
     |/         |
     |          |
     |        (o_o)
     |          | 
     |          |
     |         
     |
     |
     |
_____|______
'''
,
'''
      ___________
     |/         |
     |          |
     |        (o_o)
     |          |/ 
     |          |
     |          
     |
     |
     |
_____|______
'''
,
'''
      ___________
     |/         |
     |          |
     |        (o_o)
     |         \|/ 
     |          |
     |           
     |
     |
     |
_____|______
'''
,
'''
      ___________
     |/         |
     |          |
     |        (o_o)
     |         \|/ 
     |          |
     |         / 
     |
     |
     |
_____|______
'''
,
'''
    YOU DEAD!!!
      ___________
     |/         |
     |          |
     |        (X_X)
     |         \|/ 
     |          |
     |         / \ 
     |
     |
     |
_____|______
'''
]

#used to validate user input
ALPHABET = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']

#Declares lists of different sized words
fourWords = ['ties', 'shoe', 'wall', 'dime', 'pens', 'lips', 'toys', 'from', 'your', 'will', 'have', 'long', 'clam', 'crow', 'duck', 'dove', 'fish', 'gull', 'fowl', 'frog', 'hare', 'hair', 'hawk', 'deer', 'bull', 'bird', 'bear', 'bass', 'foal', 'moth', 'back', 'baby']
fiveWords = ['jazzy', 'faker', 'alien', 'aline', 'allot', 'alias', 'alert', 'intro', 'inlet', 'erase', 'error', 'onion', 'least', 'liner', 'linen', 'lions', 'loose', 'loner', 'lists', 'nasal', 'lunar', 'louse', 'oasis', 'nurse', 'notes', 'noose', 'otter', 'reset', 'rerun', 'ratio', 'resin', 'reuse', 'retro', 'rinse', 'roast', 'roots', 'saint', 'salad', 'ruins']
sixwords =  ['baboon', 'python',]


def main():
    #Gets menu choice from user
    choice = menu()

    #Initializes dictionary of user accounts from file
    accDct = loadAcc()

    #initializes user's account
    user = Account.Account("", "", "", "", 0, 0)

    while choice != 0:
        if choice == 1:
           user = play(user)
        if choice == 2:
            createAcc(accDct)
        if choice == 3:
           user = logIn(accDct)
        if choice == 4:
            viewAcc(user)
        choice = menu()

    saveAcc(accDct)

#Plays the game
def play(user):

    os.system("cls") #Clears screen
    hangman = 0      #Used as index for stage view
    done = False    #Used to signal when game is finished
    guessed = ['']   #Holds letters already guessed

    #Gets the game word lenght from the user
    difficulty = int(input("Chose Difficulty/Word Length:\n"\
                           "1. Easy: Four Letter Word\n"\
                           "2. Medium: Five Letter Word\n"\
                           "3. Hard: Six Letter Word\n"\
                           "Choice: "))
    #Validates input                 
    while difficulty < 1 or difficulty > 3:
        difficulty = int(input("Invalid menu choice.\n"\
                               "Reenter Choice(1-3): "))

    #Gets a random word from a different list depending on difficulty
    if difficulty == 1:
        word = random.choice(fourWords)
    if difficulty == 2:
        word = random.choice(fiveWords)
    if difficulty == 3:
        word = random.choice(sixWords)

    viewWord = list('_'*len(word))
    letters = list(word)

    while done == False:

        os.system("cls")

        print(STAGES[hangman])
        for i in range(len(word)):
            sys.stdout.write(viewWord[i])
            sys.stdout.write(" ")
        print()
        print("Guessed Letters: ")
        for i in range(len(guessed)):
            sys.stdout.write(guessed[i])
        print()

        guess = str(input("Enter guess: "))
        guess = guess.lower()

        while guess in guessed:
            guess = str(input("Already guessed that letter.\n"\
                              "Enter another guess: "))

        while len(guess) != 1:
            guess = str(input("Guess must be ONE letter.\n"\
                              "Enter another guess: "))

        while guess not in ALPHABET[0]:
            guess = str(input("Guess must be a letter.\n"\
                     "Enter another guess: "))

        if guess not in letters:
            hangman+=1

        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess in letters[i]:
                viewWord[i] = guess

        guessed += guess

        if '_' not in viewWord:
            print ("Congratulations! You correctly guessed",word)
            done = True

            win = user.get_win()
            win += 1
            username = user.get_username()
            password = user.get_password()
            name = user.get_name()
            email = user.get_email()
            loss = user.get_loss()
            user = Account.Account(username, password, name, email, win, loss)

        if hangman == 6:
            os.system("cls")
            print()
            print(STAGES[hangman])
            print("You couldn't guess the word",word.upper(),"before being hanged.")
            print("Sorry, you lose.")
            done = True

            loss = user.get_loss()
            loss += 1
            username = user.get_username()
            password = user.get_password()
            name = user.get_name()
            email = user.get_email()
            win = user.get_win()
            user = Account.Account(username, password, name, email, win, loss)






#Loads user accounts from file
def loadAcc():
    try:
        iFile = open('userAccounts.txt', 'rb')

        accDct = pickle.load(iFile)

        iFile.close

    except IOError:
        accDct = {}

    return accDct

#Displays the menu        
def menu():
    os.system('cls')
    print("Welcome to Karl-Heinz's Hangman")
    choice = int(input("1. Play Hangman\n"\
                       "2. Create Account\n"\
                       "3. Log In\n"\
                       "4. View Account Details\n"\
                       "0. Quit Program\n"\
                       "Choice: "))
    while choice < 0 or choice > 4:
        choice = int(input("Invalid Menu Choice.\n"\
                           "Reenter Choice: "))

    return choice

#Logs user in to existing account      
def logIn(accDct):
    os.system('cls')
    user = Account.Account("","","","",0,0)
    username = str(input("Enter Username(case sensitive): "))
    if username not in accDct:
        print("Account does not exist")
        os.system("pause")
        return user

    temp = Account.Account("","","","",0,0)
    temp = accDct[username]

    password = str(input("Enter Password(case sensitive): "))
    if password != temp.get_password():
        print("Incorrect password.")
        os.system("pause")
        return user

    user = accDct[username]
    return user


#Creates a new account and a new account file if one doesn't exist
def createAcc(accDct):
    os.system('cls')
    print("Enter account info:")
    username = str(input("UserName: "))

    if username in accDct:
        print("Account already exists.")
        os.system("pause")
        return

    password = str(input("Password: "))
    name = str(input("Name: "))
    email = str(input("Email: "))
    wins = 0
    loss = 0

    tempuser = Account.Account(username, password, name, email, wins, loss)

    accDct[username] = tempuser

    print("Account created.")
    os.system("pause")

def viewAcc(user):
    os.system('cls')



    print("Account Details: ")
    print("Username: ",user.get_username())
    print("Name: ",user.get_name())
    print("Email: ",user.get_email())
    print("Wins: ",user.get_win())
    print("Losses: ",user.get_loss())

    os.system("pause")






#Saves accounts dictionary to file
def saveAcc(accDct):    
    oFile = open("userAccounts.txt", "wb")

    pickle.dump(accDct, oFile)

    oFile.close()


main()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be using single leading underscore for private variables, double is for name mangling

Comment: The indentation is not correct in the Accont file, check it in the real file.

Comment: Isn't that something for code review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your play() function doesn't have a `return` statement, which means it's returning `None` as its return value. That's how you're getting `None` into your `user` variable in main(). Add a `return` statement to your play() function and you should be fine.

Comment: Wow, three answers at the same time!

Comment: Wow, I don't know how i missed that. Lack of sleep i suppose. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating *new* `Account` instances in `play` but never return these. The `user` variable in `main` then is assigned `None` because  `play` never returns anything.

Return `user` from `play` when done:

```
def play(user):
    # ....

    return user
```

Answer (score 0):

The `play` function do not return an `Account` instance. then it returns `None`. If you call the `play` function before the `viewAcc` function then user is equal to `None`